# Simulate Client Certificate based authentication through postman

Tags: authentication, ssl, postman

i am trying to simulate client certificate based authentication for my APIs in postman.

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/certificates

I have followed this document and was able to send the certificate (as shown in postman console).

In server side i look for ssl_client_cert header name to check if it is a certificate based authentication (as i have other modes of authentication too).

But it seems the header is not being sent by postman.

Is there anything else i need to activate in postman. What is hitting me is that i have kept the authorization mode in postman as no auth. I don't find any cert auth mode to select. Am i missing anything.

best Regards,

Saurav